# Do Office.js add-ins need internet access to load their local content?

Tags: office-js

I have an Office.js add-in which runs entirely on the client machine, served by localhost using Windows operating system. The manifests are in a local shared folder and all of the required files and javascripts are also stored locally (including the appropriate additional files specific for that client scripts) so theoretically the add-in has no need for internet access to work properly.

If the add-in is first loaded while it is online and internet cache is populated, then the offline behavior is [as this answer describes it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240650/do-office-add-ins-always-require-internet-access-to-work#37258684). However if Temporary Internet Files are deleted and the add-in is launched while it has no internet access, it loads the html markup, but then it hangs and seemingly it doesn't do anything. I inspected network traffic and there cannot be seen any attempts to load any scripts.

The add-in's web pages can be loaded with a browser without any problem even when the Temporary Internet Files are cleared entirely.

I know that Office.js add-ins are web based, but is there a way to make the add-in work totally offline, not depending on Temporary Internet Files when everything is provided locally?

Comment: How are you referencing Office.js?

Comment: Have you tried using the Nuget package for Office-js or the experimental NPM [package](https://github.com/officedev/office-js). It should work as long as you host things locally and put the manifest on a shared location.

Comment: Office.js is referenced via relative path from index.html (the entry html):
<script src="../../lib/office/office.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

That lib/office folder contains all files and folders from the master/dist directory of the NPM repository's current release (^1.0.0.0).