# Office Web add-in Offline experience

Tags: office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, word-web-addins

I want bring an offline experience to the Outlook Web add-in that I am trying to build targeting the Outlook windows client. My idea is to use modern offline methods like service worker. This applies for Word Add-in as well. It would be nice to have something working in offline mode.

I found that web client that Outlook uses to render the add-in , does not support Service Worker. I am not in favor of using app cache to get offline experience , since it is not a web standard anymore.

Is the service worker support for Office Web add-in being planned by the Office add-in team? Or is there any other approach that is being suggested?

Answer (score 1):

Offline running is not supported for Office/Outlook Add-ins. But it's a good idea. Please vote up [this request at Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/36034516-make-possible-to-install-office-add-ins-permanentl).

Comment: In an answer to similar question , it is mentioned that html application cache works in Office 2013 . I have tried that in Office 2016 and could not replicate. Does Office 2016 support application cache?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240650/do-office-add-ins-always-require-internet-access-to-work